# Curve rotation problem

Tags: bezier-curves, edit-mode

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now without getting anywhere so could somebody help me please?

I'm trying to create a shape that starts flat and ends the same way as on the image below.

[image]

Instead I've been achieving these results image2 and image3. I've been trying to rotate but without getting the result that I wanted.

[image]

[image]

How can I get one curved shape that starts as in image 3 and ends as in image 2?
To create this I made a curve and applied two modifiers array modifier and curve modifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to rotate an object in 'Edit Mode' (using *proportional editing*). Remember to match the curve origin with the object origin.

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This will solve my problem!

Comment: Glad to hear that:). If that solved your problem please hit the 'accept answer' button.